# How to get a backtrace from a SystemStackError: stack level too deep?

Tags: ruby

Often I get hard to debug infinite recursions when coding ruby. Is there a way to get a backtrace out of a `SystemStackError` to find out, where exactly the infinite loop occurs?

### Example

Given some methods `foo`, `bar` and `baz` which call each other in a loop:

```
def foo
  bar
end

def bar
  baz
end

def baz
  foo
end

foo
```

When I run this code, I just get the message `test.rb:6: stack level too deep (SystemStackError)`. It would be useful to get at least the last 100 lines of the stack, so I could immediately see this is a loop between `foo`, `bar` and `baz`, like this:

```
test.rb:6: stack level too deep (SystemStackError)
  test.rb:2:in `foo'
  test.rb:10:in `baz'
  test.rb:6:in `bar'
  test.rb:2:in `foo'
  test.rb:10:in `baz'
  test.rb:6:in `bar'
  test.rb:2:in `foo'
  [...]
```

Is there any way to accomplish this?

**EDIT:**

As you may see from the answer below, Rubinius can do it. Unfortunately some [rubinius bugs](http://github.com/rubinius/rubinius/issues/1692) prevent me from using it with the software I'd like to debug. So to be precise the question is:

**How do I get a backtrace with MRI (the default ruby) 1.9?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently this was tracked as [feature 6216](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/6216) and fixed in Ruby 2.2.

```
$ ruby system-stack-error.rb
system-stack-error.rb:6:in `bar': stack level too deep (SystemStackError)
        from system-stack-error.rb:2:in `foo'
        from system-stack-error.rb:10:in `baz'
        from system-stack-error.rb:6:in `bar'
        from system-stack-error.rb:2:in `foo'
        from system-stack-error.rb:10:in `baz'
        from system-stack-error.rb:6:in `bar'
        from system-stack-error.rb:2:in `foo'
        from system-stack-error.rb:10:in `baz'
         ... 10067 levels...
        from system-stack-error.rb:10:in `baz'
        from system-stack-error.rb:6:in `bar'
        from system-stack-error.rb:2:in `foo'
        from system-stack-error.rb:13:in `<main>'
```

Comment: I'm using 2.3.1 and this does nothing... Am I missing something?

Comment: Yesterday I had a stack error and tried it. Nothing happened. I resolved the issue then and just tried it again to see and got a no such file or directory LoadError.

Comment: I've actually got the same problem, both with 2.3.x and 2.4.3 (on Windows). I also tried catching the exception and looking at its `backtrace`, but for some weird reason that gives `nil`.

Answer (score 45):

Another method for those finding this question later... An [excellent gist](https://gist.github.com/jbgo/4493822) provides instructions on enabling a trace function in the console and printing all function calls to a file.  Just tested on 1.9.3-p194 and it worked great.

Including here in case the gist goes away someday:

```
$enable_tracing = false
$trace_out = open('trace.txt', 'w')

set_trace_func proc { |event, file, line, id, binding, classname|
  if $enable_tracing && event == 'call'
    $trace_out.puts "#{file}:#{line} #{classname}##{id}"
  end
}

$enable_tracing = true
a_method_that_causes_infinite_recursion_in_a_not_obvious_way()
```

Comment: This worked especially well for me in conjunction with @gerry-gleason's tip.  By raising an exception, I'm not overwhelmed by the calls that aren't recursive.

Comment: huh, very stupid you can't get a meaningful stacktrace when you most need it... thanks, this worked for me

Comment: Combine this answer with mine below that tests the stack depth and raises an exception at some limit and you have a sort of automated detection. Oh, that's its own answer, I'll vote that up.

Answer (score 21):

This has been a somewhat vexing problem that I've had from time to time in debugging ruby/rails.  I just discovered a workable technique to detect the stack growing out of bounds before it crashed the system stack and the real backtrace gets lost or garbled.  The basic pattern is:

```
raise "crash me" if caller.length > 500
```

bump up the 500 until it doesn't fire prematurely and you will have a nice trace of your growing stack problem.

Comment: The problem is where to put it. You can't put this in every single step in a program. You can perhaps use this for figuring out the location by trial-and-error after an error is raised, but you can not in advance locate this in code.

Comment: still a faster way of finding out something :)

Comment: Using `caller_locations.length` is more efficient, particularly if you're using @elliot-nelson's tracing technique.

Comment: sawa - Put this in a set_trace_func proc, surrounded with an if statement - 'if event == "call"  && caller.length > 500'

Answer (score 14):

Here:

```
begin
  foo
rescue SystemStackError
  puts $!
  puts caller[0..100]
end
```

The method `Kernel#caller` returns a stack backtrace as an array, so this prints the first 0 to 100 entries in the backtrace. Because `caller` can be called at any time (and used for some pretty weird things) even if Ruby doesn't print backtrace for SystemStackErrors, you can still get a backtrace.

Comment: Does not work on my ruby 1.9.3-p194 with the following code: https://gist.github.com/3136778. It just outputs `recursion.rb:6: stack level too deep (SystemStackError)`. Did you try it yourself? Which ruby version are you using?

Comment: @iblue: See edit. That should fix it. Gave me a stack trace of where `foo` was being called from, and my `foo` was just `def foo; foo; end`.

Comment: Still does not print a backtrace containing any of the methods foo, bar or baz. It outputs `stack level too deep` and `recursion.rb:13:in `<main>'`, which is the line the begin block starts. Does not help.

Comment: @iblue: Then I doubt anything will help. I'll delete the answer so the question is unanswered again.

Comment: @iblue: Wait! What happens if you use `$!.backtrace[0..100]` rather than `caller`?

Comment: Then I get the source of the Exception (`recursion.rb:6`), but still no backtrace.

Comment: @iblue: I guess Ruby is preventing you from getting backtrace. When I have `foo` print a backtrace, it says that it's been in `foo`. It also  comes close to crashing bash on a powerful system, which may be why Ruby prevents a backtrace. I had it count how many times it executes, and on a Mac Mini with 8GB RAM and a Core i5, it went ~9500 times.

Comment: My theory is that a `SystemStackError` occurs, when the OS detects a stack overflow (that why it's called `SystemStackError` instead of `StackError`), so  the backtrace may be scrambled and that may be why ruby does not print it. May be there is still some option to get a backtrace.

Comment: @iblue: I did some research, but didn't find anything. Maybe in an alternate implementation it will work. I can try Rubinus, JRuby, and MacRuby.

Comment: @iblue: Rubinus: Nothing. JRuby: Hits a cap, gives option to see a (rather cryptic) trace with the `-w` option or increase stack size. MacRuby: My install is broken. Jruby might have something for you here. And, they have an option to increase the stack too.

Comment: I tried it in rbx (rubinius). It works. Unfortunately the error happens in a rails app which uses draper, which uses a syntax not supported by rbx - See my bug report on https://github.com/rubinius/rubinius/issues/1692.

Comment: @iblue: Really? On my RBX I got nothing for the trace. My JRuby gave my a JVM trace, which might be of some use. You might look at JRuby.

Comment: Just try the example in the question and you will get a nice (even colored!) backtrace from the default rbx exception handler.

Comment: not sure about example but this is a totally unreliable method to getting a stack trace. Maybe if your rescue is very close or inside the recurring code, then it might help. But otherwise it gives you totally irrelevant data. Answer of @elliot-nelson is what got me going. Although it's so stupid of ruby to behave like that...

Answer (score 7):

Combining suggestions from several answers, this will throw an error (with stack trace) when your call stack gets too deep. This will slow down all method calls, so you should try to put it as close to where you think the infinite loop is happening as you can.

```
set_trace_func proc {
  |event, file, line, id, binding, classname| 
  if event == "call"  && caller_locations.length > 500
    fail "stack level too deep"
  end
}
```

Comment: Also suggested below, you might add this change to the answer to make it a little faster: Using caller_locations.length is more efficient, particularly if you're using @elliot-nelson's tracing technique

Answer (score 5):

If you happen to use pry, this will actually let you break into the method call chain that's gone too deep.

```
set_trace_func proc { |event, file, line, id, proc_binding, classname|
  if !$pried && proc_binding && proc_binding.eval( "caller.size" ) > 200
    $pried = true
    proc_binding.pry
  end
}
```

Comment: interesting, didn't try it but is an interesting debugging technique

Comment: So, this is similar to the above, but you end up in a pry session as if you stopped at a breakpoint? (vs. throwing an exception)

Comment: Where should I put this code?

Answer (score 3):

You can get this kind of stack trace with Ruby 1.8. If the presence of 1.9 style syntax (eg `{foo: 42}`) is the only issue, then compile [Ruby 1.8 head](https://rvm.io//rubies/installing/).

Comment: Can you elaborate on why this doesn't work in 1.9? I can't find any other reference to that being the case or why...

Comment: @bjeanes I can't really remember, but I may have been thinking of how `assert_nothing_raised` differs in behavior between 1.8 and 1.9, which is probably a test/unit versus minitest thing.

Answer (score 2):

I tried many of the things here, but could not find where the recursion was (I am using Ruby 2.0).

Then, I tried "the stupid thing".  I ran the problem code (in my case, unit tests) in Terminal, and then pressed `Ctrl-C` when I thought the offensive test was running (a few `puts` calls helped).  Sure enough, I got a full backtrace :)

I had a full 3 or 4 seconds to respond on a 2013 Macbook Pro.