# "LocalJumpError: unexpected return" after adding a set_trace_func to debug a SystemStackError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, return, trace

I have a SystemStackError whose cause is difficult to find, so to find out did as recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28680027/226958): I added this block:

```
module ApplicationHelper
  set_trace_func proc {
    |event, file, line, id, binding, classname|
    if event == "call"  && caller_locations.length > 500
      fail "stack level too deep"
    end
  }
end
```

I added the block above to `app/helpers/application_helper.rb`, not sure it is the best place.

**PROBLEM:**

Immediately after adding this, my app started failing with the following error:

```
#<LocalJumpError: unexpected return>
INFO -- : worker=0 spawning...
ERROR -- : reaped #<Process::Status: pid 1440 exit 1> worker=0
INFO -- : worker=0 spawned pid=1443
INFO -- : Refreshing Gem list
```

What did I do wrong?
Did I put the `set_trace_func` at the wrong place?

Answer (score 1):

Ok. Step by step.

We have two different exceptions here:

1.- SystemStackError: This can be due to an infinite loop or very big stack. We need more info to debug this. Options:

- Lazy option: Please paste your backtrace.
- DIY option: Have a interactive debug session, I know an easy way to accomplish this. IMHO `set_func_trace` is too low level (Whatever this means in Ruby :p) for what you are trying to debug:

  - Add `pry` (https://github.com/pry/pry) and `pry-stack-explorer` (https://github.com/pry/pry-stack_explorer) to your project.
  - Add the following to your `ApplicationController`.

    ```
    rescue_from SystemStackError do |exception|
      binding.pry
    end
    ```
  - Power up your server and replicate you bug.
  - Once in the console, you can inspect the backtrace with `exception.backtrace` and navigate the stack using some magic provided by `pry-stack-explorer`, which uses `binding.callers` internally.

    E.g. `show-stack` then moving to the desired frame using `frame X`. Inside the offending frame you can then inspect all the behaviour and attributes.

2.- LocalJumpError: This looks like this line: `fail "stack level too deep"` inside your `set_trace_func`, is raising an `RuntimeError`, son of `StandardError` which affects the behaviour of a rescue previously defined in the stack, very probably in ActiveSupport dependency loading mechanisms.

I was not able to reproduce this but if you inspect your local ActiveSupport installation there's a high chance there's a hint in that specific version. E.g. `less $(bundle show activesupport)/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb` from your shell.

I'll cite ruby-doc.org: LocalJumpError means having a `return` inside a block call or yielding inside a method that does not have a block.

Comment: "*paste your backtrace*": If I understand correctly, you want me to insert *somewhere* a Ruby instruction that will output the stack trace to some kind of log? Problem: the *somewhere* is not known yet, I don't where the infinite loop is happening.

Comment: My `$(bundle show activesupport)/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb` does not contain the string `trace`. It has a `protected def log_call(*args)` though. It also contains the `return` keyword several times.

Comment: 1.- If you follow my DIY option, you'll end up with a rails console in the server process after you replicate your bug. In that console you'll be able to get the backtrace by using `exception.backtrace`.

Comment: 2.- Why are you looking for the string "trace"? I want to know more about your logic. I'd suggest you to read more about ruby blocks and how `yield` works.