# QtRuby: Stack Level too deep (SystemStackError)

Tags: ruby, qtruby

I have the following code:

```
require 'qt'

class Menu < Qt::Widget
  slots 'on_clicked_uAuth()'
  slots 'quit()'

  def initialize(parent = nil)
    super(parent)
    setWindowTitle "Menu"
    uAuth_ui
    exit_ui
    resize 350, 500
    move 300, 300
    show
  end
  def uAuth_ui
    uAuth = Qt::PushButton.new 'Auth', self
    uAuth.resize 150, 35
    uAuth.move 100, 100
    connect uAuth, SIGNAL('clicked()'), self, SLOT('on_clicked_uAuth()')
  end
  def exit_ui
    exit = Qt::PushButton.new 'Exit', self
    exit.resize 120, 40
    exit.move 115, 420
    connect exit, SIGNAL('clicked()'), self, SLOT('quit()')
  end
end

app = Qt::Application.new(ARGV)
Menu.new
app.exec
```

When I click either button, I get the following error:

```
stack level too deep (SystemStackError)
```

Can someone let me know what changes I should make so that, when I click the buttons, I get the next screen?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I had to change `require 'qt'` to `require 'Qt'` on my system, because I use a case-sensitive filesystem and just because of compatibility reasons I would recommend using the correct case.

Once I was able to run your script I realized the stack trace is really just the `SystemStackError` message you provided. So I looked a bit around and found a useful snippet [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28680027/595304): (Apparently you don't need this in Ruby 2.2 anymore but I don't have it installed right now so I didn't bother trying out)

```
set_trace_func proc {
  |event, file, line, id, binding, classname| 
  if event == "call"  && caller_locations.length > 500
    fail "stack level too deep"
  end
}
```

You add this somewhere before executing the app and the stack trace will already be more useful:

```
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.1.0/Qt/qtruby4.rb:2531:in `debug_level'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.1.0/Qt/qtruby4.rb:2714:in `do_method_missing'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.1.0/Qt/qtruby4.rb:2711:in `do_method_missing'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.1.0/Qt/qtruby4.rb:2667:in `do_method_missing'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.1.0/Qt/qtruby4.rb:469:in `method_missing'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.1.0/Qt/qtruby4.rb:469:in `qt_metacall'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.1.0/Qt/qtruby4.rb:469:in `method_missing'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.1.0/Qt/qtruby4.rb:469:in `qt_metacall'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.1.0/Qt/qtruby4.rb:469:in `method_missing'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.1.0/Qt/qtruby4.rb:469:in `qt_metacall'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.1.0/Qt/qtruby4.rb:469:in `method_missing'
```

So somehow it got stuck in an endless loop of calling a method that is not present (therefore stack level ends up being too deep).

Now I wasn't able to fix your issue, but it seems that some method is missing. I can't see a declaration of `on_clicked_uAuth()` anywhere and I'm not sure either if `quit()` can be accessed with the `SLOT` like that.

**Update:** I'm pretty certain now the issue is the `SLOT` invocation.
For example this works perfectly fine:

```
connect(exit, SIGNAL(:clicked)) { puts "Hello world." }
```

Now the problem here is that `quit` is not implemented on `QtWidget` but rather on the application. However you can just close the window and the application will terminate by default if there are no more windows open:

```
connect(exit, SIGNAL(:clicked)) { close() }
```

Comment: Even I felt the error is related to defining on_click_uAuth(). Basically, I need to write a method  for on_click_uAuth() such that on click of button, it should direct me to a new window . Any suggestions would be welcomed

Comment: Write the method in the Ruby class and connect the signal like in the last code snippet in my answer (replace the close method call with the one you want to make, if it's only a short action you could even write it directly into the block)

Comment: I have another class defined named as "Auth" which is in a different file . So how do I call that method from another file with click of on_click_uAuth?

Comment: To call the method you need an instance of said class. (You invoke methods on instances/objects.) Now you have to decide where you want to create the instance and where you'll need it. Also if your class is in another file you have to import that file. In Ruby you most likely want to use require_relative for that.

Comment: The above block of code worked for me . It was of great help .